# Design pattern for multithreaded java application

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns

I have a backend that receives requests on a function

```
update(by_whom, payload);
```

I then process the request, and answer accordingly.

**Every time a user sends a request**, the message goes through several processing objects before an answer is produced.

Now, how would I go about handling each user in his very own thread? I don't understand how to dispatch events to tailor-made threads.

**Example:**

`User 1` sends first request -> We make a ThreadUser1 and handle it there.

`User 2` sends first request -> We make a ThreadUser2 and handle it there, doesn't matter if request1 from user1 hasn't finished, they can run together.

`User 1` sends second request, **the first one sent by him hasn't finished** -> We dispatch this request on the threadUser1, and it will therefore wait for request1 to finish.

Basically, upon receiving a request, it should only be put in queue behind those sent by the same user, and be run concurrently with everything else.

**A way I thought would work:**

I thought about posting every request in a concurrent list from the main thread, and have threads check that list (**while true**), and pick the requests from the user which they belong to.

A few problems with this: 
- I'd need to check the whole list everytime for a request by the right user.

- This assumes I already have a thread running for every possible user, which I don't, I only know the id of a user when he first texts.
- Efficiency, potentially a huge amount of loops checking the same list over and over.
- **A thread should stop** after all the requests from that user are finished.

On that last point: it's because I need to have a limit **MAX** whereby any requests received while we already have **MAX** threads running, with these new requests not belonging to any current user (*aka running thread*) are handled normally (queuing in the main thread, one after the other).

I really don't know how to go about this and I'd be very glad if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have a map `user -> tasks`. When a request comes in, add a list of tasks to that map and schedule a worker thread to work on this list - if concurrently there arrives another request from the same user, you'll find its list and you can simply add to that. Let the server control the access to the map, i.e. every worker has to notify its completion to let the server clean up (or reschedule). Then let the list (e.g. a [queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)) be synchronised s.t. the thread can pull newly scheduled request from it asynchronously.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't have any shared state between threads, you could use a queue per Thread that keep requests associated to one thread. To handle the "MAX" number of threads I would suggest using a FixedThreadPool (see `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int))? If necessary I can write a small gist

Answer (score -1):

You need your threads to know both what task they are working on, and what user they are working for.  However, you want a limited number of threads.

I think architecturally, the best way to do this is to start the limited number of threads, and have them able to handle tasks from arbitrary users, but not permit multiple threads to work for the same user at the same time.

To do this, keep three Sets of user objects, one Set for all users with incomplete tasks, one Set for users which have a thread assigned to them, and one Set for users which don't have a thread assigned to them.  Put all three Sets in a single, thread safe user tracking object.  You will also need a Map from users to tasks, or if you need tasks to be completed in the order they were queued, from users to queues of tasks.

When you queue a task, synchronize on the user tracking object, then check the Set of users with incomplete tasks.  If the relevant user does not exist, create it and put it in the Set of users with incomplete tasks and also in the Set of users with no associated thread.  Then put the task in a thread safe Map from users to tasks.  Finally, exit synchronization on the user tracking object.  The easiest way to do this synchronization is to put this processing in a synchronized method in the user tracking object.

Threads are each assigned to a user, which may be null.  The thread starts its loop by synchronizing on the user tracking object, then obtains a task if one is available.

To obtain a task, the thread first checks whether it is already assigned to a nonnull user.  If it is, it checks the Map for tasks for that user.  If it finds one, the thread removes the task from the map for servicing.  If it finds no tasks for the user, it removes the user from the Set of users with incomplete tasks, and also from the Set of users with assigned threads, then sets the user it is assigned to to null.

If the thread is assigned to a null user, it checks the Set of users without assigned threads.  If it finds one, it assigns itself to that user and moves that user from the Set of users without assigned threads to the Set of users with assigned threads.  The thread then checks the Map for tasks associated with that user - there is guaranteed to be one - and removes it for servicing.

After obtaining the task, but before servicing it, the thread exits the code block that was synchronized on the user tracking object.  Again, it's probably best to use a synchronized method in the user tracking object for the process of obtaining the task.  After exiting the synchronized block, the thread completes the task.  If the thread ultimately did not obtain a task, because none were available other than to users which already had threads assigned, the thread can sleep for a while before waking up and rechecking, but this should be outside the synchronization block.

You can probably figure out specific classes to use yourself.  You can get more sophisticated by having threads exit rather than sleeping, then restarting them as necessary, but it might be best to keep things simple at first.